# Extracting specific fields from a log file and export it to csv file using C#

Tags: c#, linux

This is the code that I have written in C# which shows the contains in the sample.log file which is 110MB in size.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            FileStream fs = new FileStream("sample.log", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
            string StrFromFile;
            StringBuilder ResultStr = new StringBuilder();


          while ((StrFromFile = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
          { 
            // your separator char seems to be char 1
            string[] SplitStrs = StrFromFile.Split(new char[] {(char)1});        
            for (int i = 0; i < SplitStrs.Length; i++)
            {   
                if (SplitStrs[i].StartsWith("52="))
                {
                    ResultStr.Append(SplitStrs[i] + " ");
                }
                else if (SplitStrs[i].StartsWith("55="))
                {
                    ResultStr.Append(SplitStrs[i] + " ");
                }
                else if (SplitStrs[i].StartsWith("132="))
                {
                    ResultStr.Append(SplitStrs[i] + " ");
                }
                else if (SplitStrs[i].StartsWith("133="))
                {
                    ResultStr.Append(SplitStrs[i] + " ");
                }
                else if (SplitStrs[i].StartsWith("35="))
                {
                    ResultStr.Append(SplitStrs[i] + " ");
                }   
            }

            Console.WriteLine(ResultStr);
            ResultStr.Length = 0;
         }
            sr.Close();
            fs.Close();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

I am getting this output,

**Output:**

```
35=5 52=20101219-18:05:01.522 
35=A 52=20101219-18:06:01.504 
35=A 52=20101219-18:06:02 
35=1 52=20101219-18:06:02 
35=R 52=20101219-18:06:01.847 55=EUR/USD
```

Now the problem is **how do I write this output in csv file?**
Any idea.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than write your own: [Log Parser 2.2](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en):

> Log parser is a powerful, versatile
>   tool that provides universal query
>   access to text-based data such as log
>   files, XML files and CSV files, as
>   well as key data sources on the
>   Windows® operating system such as the
>   Event Log, the Registry, the file
>   system, and Active Directory®. You
>   tell Log Parser what information you
>   need and how you want it processed.
>   The results of your query can be
>   custom-formatted in text based output,
>   or they can be persisted to more
>   specialty targets like SQL, SYSLOG, or
>   a chart.

- [Log Parser Examples](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee692659.aspx)
- [Coding Horror: Microsoft LogParser](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html)
- [Forensic Log Parsing with Microsoft's LogParser](http://www.symantec.com/connect/articles/forensic-log-parsing-microsofts-logparser)

Log Parser's built-in Input Formats can retrieve data from the following sources:

- IIS log files (W3C, IIS, NCSA, Centralized Binary Logs, HTTP Error logs, URLScan logs, ODBC logs)
- Windows Event Log
- Generic XML, CSV, TSV and W3C - formatted text files (e.g. Exchange Tracking log files, Personal Firewall log files, Windows Media® Services log files, FTP log files, SMTP log files, etc.)
- Windows registry
- Active Directory Objects
- File and Directory information
- NetMon .cap capture files
- Extended/Combined NCSA log files

For Linux you could use [AWStats](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/):

> AWStats can analyze a lot of log
>   formats: Apache NCSA combined log
>   files (XLF/ELF) or common (CLF), IIS
>   log files (W3C), WebStar native log
>   files and other web, proxy, wap or
>   streaming servers log files (but also
>   ftp or mail log files).

[AWStats logfile analyzer 7.0 Documentation: FAQ](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_faq.html#LOGFORMAT)

Also: [Logparser (Microsoft's one) or similar for Unix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185665/logparser-microsofts-one-or-similar-for-unix)

Comment: My question is how to extract specific fields from a log file and export it to csv file using C#

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at filehelpers: [www.filehelpers.com](http://www.filehelpers.com/), an open source .Net library for parsing and saving CSV files.
Very easy and very powerful